# How to extract some row in vertical condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have dataframe below

```
    A B C   
1   a 0 6  
1   b 1 5
1   c 0 8
1   d 0 9
2   e 0 1
2   f 1 2 
2   g 0 3
3   h 0 4
3   i 0 5
3   j 0 6
```

first, I would like to extract df.B==1

```
   A B C
1  b 1 5
2  f 1 2
```

second,I would like to extract the row around the number of Column C (+ -1, in this case the row c 0 8 is next to b 1 5,but the number of df.C=8 so this column would be dropped.If df.C=4or6 this row will be added) It does not matter whether they are next to each other or not.

```
  A B C
1 a 0 6
1 b 1 5
2 e 0 1
2 f 1 2
2 g 0 3
```

I want to get the dataframe above. How can I do this?

First I tried

```
df[df.B==1]
```

But,I couldn't figure out next step..

Comment: Your desired output for part 2 doesn't seem to correspond to your original dataframe -- the e,0,1 row becomes e,0,4 (the part 1 outputs don't seem to match either) and it's not clear what "around the number of Column C" means.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: sorry, I just edited...

Comment: You accepted an answer which includes the row `1   c 0 8` in the output, but it's not there in your desired output.  Why?

Comment: Thank you for comment, I overlooked ! sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Er, I'm not sure you get how this works.  You're supposed to edit your question to explain how to get your output.  *Why* do you not want the row `1 c 0 8`?

Comment: I'm certain that there is an answer to the question you have.  The only thing getting in the way of that answer is your ability to explain the problem.  I can give you many ways to select those rows.  I need to understand **why** you want those rows.

Comment: thank you for comment. and sorry for inconvenience .this problem came from medical data. the columnC means the year and month (ex 201701) the column B represents the flag.(1 means someone is in hospital,0 means someone's hospital visit)  I want to extract the hospital visit record near hospitalization(for example +- 2 month...) so I have to investigate the number near hospitalization flag.

Answer (score 3):

```
# find where `B` is one
bs = np.where(df.B.values == 1)[0]

# union `bs` with + 1 and - 1
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate([bs - 1, bs, bs + 1]))

# don't go below zero or above last row
idx = idx[(0 <= idx) & (idx < len(df))]

# use `iloc` to index correct rows
df.iloc[idx]

   A  B  C
1  a  0  6
1  b  1  5
1  c  0  8
2  e  0  1
2  f  1  2
2  g  0  3
```

Comment: thank you for cooperation! I would like to the row whose number of  not columnC  is near the first step's row( not the index)

Answer (score 1):

okay its a bit confusing (specially because u changed the numbers from first example to second to third) but from what i understood you want to get all rows with:

```
B==1
```

and from those rows, you want to get the rows with equal index value and C+-1 from the C of the one with B==1 
(please correct me if i got that wrong)

I would do that the following way:

being df = your original dataframe

```
DF = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['A','B','C'])

index_list = []

for i in np.arange(len(df)):

    ref_index = df.index[i]

    if df.iloc[i]['B'] == 1:

        DF.loc[len(DF)] = df.iloc[i]
        index_list.append(df.index[i])

    if df.iloc[i]['B'] == 0:

        try:

            ref_C = df[df['B']==1].loc[ df.index[i]]['C']

        except:

            ref_C = np.nan

        if ((df.iloc[i]['C'] == ref_C + 1)|(df.iloc[i]['C'] == ref_C - 1)):

        DF.loc[len(DF)] = df.iloc[i]
        index_list.append(df.index[i])            

DF.index = index_list
```

hope that is it, if it helps upvote/check answer, peace mate!